# DCGAN - Issue in understanding code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

This a part of the code for a Deconvolutional-Convoltional Generative Adversarial Network (DC-GAN)

```
discriminator.trainable = False
ganInput = Input(shape=(100,))
# getting the output of the generator
# and then feeding it to the discriminator
# new model = D(G(input))
x = generator(ganInput)
ganOutput = discriminator(x)
gan = Model(input=ganInput, output=ganOutput)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
```

Issue 1 - I do not understand what the line ganInput = Input(shape=(100,)) does. Clearly ganInput is a variable but what is Input? Is it a function ? If Input is a function then what will ganInput contain ?

Issue 2 - What is the role of the `Model` API ? I read about in the keras documentation but failed to understand what it is doing here.

Please ask for any further clarification / details you need.

Keras with TensorFlow backend
COMPLETE SOURCE CODE :
https://github.com/yashk2810/DCGAN-Keras/blob/master/DCGAN.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line `ganInput = Input(shape=(100,))` is just defining the shape of your input
which is a tensor of shape (100,)

The model will include all layers required in the computation of output given input. In the case of multi-input or multi-output models, you can use lists as well:

```
model = Model(inputs=[ganInput1, ganInput2], outputs=[ganOutput1, ganOutput2, ganOutput3])
```

Which means to compute ganOutput1, ganOutput2, ganOutput3 the Model api requires 
input layers ganInput1, ganInput2

This is necessary for backtracking so that way the Model api has what it needs to calculate the output

this line loads the mnist data : `(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()` .... `X_train` and `Y_train` has training data and its corresponding target values .... `X_test`, `Y_test` has training data and its corresponding target values

```
# ======================================================
# Here the data is being loaded 
# X_train = training data, Y_train = training targets 
# X_test = testing data , Y_test = testing targets 
# ======================================================
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# ================================================
# Reshaping the training and testing data
# He has added one extra dimension which is always one
# ================================================
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)


X_train = X_train.astype('float32')

# ================================================
# Initially pixel values are in range of 0-255
# he makes the pixel values to be between -1 to 1
#==================================================
X_train = (X_train - 127.5) / 127.5

X_train.shape

# ======================================================================
# He builds the generator model over here 
# 1] Dense layer with no of neurons = 128*7*7 & takes 100 numbers as input
# 2] Applying Batch Normalization
# 3] Upsampling layer
# 4] Convolution layer with activation LeakyRELU
# 5] Applying BatchNormalization
# 6] UpSampling2D layer
# 7] Convolution layer with activation LeakyRELU
# ======================================================================
generator = Sequential([
        Dense(128*7*7, input_dim=100, activation=LeakyReLU(0.2)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Reshape((7,7,128)),
        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same', activation=LeakyReLU(0.2)),
        BatchNormalization(),
        UpSampling2D(),
        Convolution2D(1, 5, 5, border_mode='same', activation='tanh')
    ])

generator.summary()

# ======================================================================
# He builds the discriminator model over here 
# 1] Convolution layer which takes as input an image of shape (28, 28, 1)
# 2] Dropout layer
# 3] Convolution layer for down-sampling with LeakyReLU as activation
# 4] Dropout layer
# 5] Flatten layer to flatten the output
# 6] 1 output node with sigmoid activation
# ======================================================================
discriminator = Sequential([
        Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, subsample=(2,2), input_shape=(28,28,1), border_mode='same', activation=LeakyReLU(0.2)),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, subsample=(2,2), border_mode='same', activation=LeakyReLU(0.2)),
        Dropout(0.3),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

discriminator.summary()

generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())

discriminator.trainable = False

# =====================================================================
# Remember above generator takes 100 numbers as input in the first layer
# Dense(128*7*7, input_dim=100, activation=LeakyReLU(0.2))
# Input(shape=(100,)) returns a tensor of this shape (100,)
# ====================================================================
ganInput = Input(shape=(100,))
# getting the output of the generator
# and then feeding it to the discriminator
# new model = D(G(input))

# ===========================================================
# giving the input tensor of shape (100,) to generator model 
# ===========================================================
x = generator(ganInput)

# ===========================================================
# the output of generator will be of shape (batch_size, 28, 28, 1)  
# this output of generator will go to discriminator as input 
# Remember we have defined discriminator input as shape (28, 28, 1)
# ===========================================================
ganOutput = discriminator(x)

# =========================================================================
# Now it is clear that generators output is needed as input to discriminator
# You have to tell this to Model api for backpropogation
# Your Model api is the whole model you have built
# it tells you that your model is a combination of generator and discriminator model where that data flow is from generator to discriminator
# YOUR_Model = generator -> discriminator
# This is something like you want to train generator and discriminator as one single model and not as two different models
# but at the same time they are actually being trained individually (Hope this makes sense)
# =========================================================================
gan = Model(input=ganInput, output=ganOutput)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
gan.summary()

def train(epoch=10, batch_size=128):
    batch_count = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size

    for i in range(epoch):
        for j in tqdm(range(batch_count)):
            # Input for the generator
            noise_input = np.random.rand(batch_size, 100)

            # getting random images from X_train of size=batch_size 
            # these are the real images that will be fed to the discriminator
            image_batch = X_train[np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)]

            # these are the predicted images from the generator
            predictions = generator.predict(noise_input, batch_size=batch_size)

            # the discriminator takes in the real images and the generated images
            X = np.concatenate([predictions, image_batch])

            # labels for the discriminator
            y_discriminator = [0]*batch_size + [1]*batch_size

            # Let's train the discriminator
            discriminator.trainable = True
            discriminator.train_on_batch(X, y_discriminator)

            # Let's train the generator
            noise_input = np.random.rand(batch_size, 100)
            y_generator = [1]*batch_size
            discriminator.trainable = False
            gan.train_on_batch(noise_input, y_generator)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more as to what `model` does taking into consideration ONLY AND ONLY this code and this use case of `model`'

Comment: I have edited my answer ... Check out my explanation

Comment: Just one more thing, when i call the `gan` model is the call going to the `gan` model as a separate entity or is the call going to first the `discriminator` and then the `generator`. What I mean by that is that are there 3 models in the code namely `gan , discriminator , generator` or just 2 namely ` discriminator and generator` and the `gan` is just a combination of them both.

Comment: There are three models `gan` which is combination of `generator` and `discriminator` and other two are `generator` and `discriminator`.. I think you should check out online how GAN actually works than you will have a clear understanding

Comment: I dont think you understood my question correctly. I know that in an actual GAN there are 3 models. I am talking about the background implementation here in the code. Are there 3 models in the background or 2 and when a call to `gan` is made a call to the `discriminator` and `generator` goes or `gan` is separate from generator and discriminator. If it is separate then how are the weights of the generator updated because we are not training it explicitly.